# Microphone not working

Tags: ubuntu, audio

My microphone is not working. I'm using front panel for it. Headphones are working fine. I tried several things and none worked. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Have you unmuted all "Capture" items in `alsamixer`? (Just a start, some aren't necessary but it should show you if it works at all.

Comment: Usually it's because there's a volume control set to zero somewhere. Sometimes multiple volume controls are set for the same device, and if any of them is zero, zero times anything means you don't hear anything.